# Identifying microwave diode that goes from transformer to capacitor

Tags: microwave-oven

I have a Panasonic [Microwave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22qDp.jpg) oven (Model: nn-mx25wf). A couple months ago the fuse blew and had to replace it along with the capacitor and diode that connects from the capacitor to the chassis. The original capacitor had 3 terminals on the left side and one on the right. The new capacitor I got just had 2 terminals on each side.

[image]

It seems that when I tried to splice the copper wire with the high voltage solid aluminum wire with the diode, the solid aluminum wires broke off.

Now I need a new diode, but the letters erased off of it and not sure what it is. One side of the diode connects to one of the capacitor connector while the other to the other side of the capacitor.

Need some help on identifying the diode and proper splicing technic or hardware necessary to splice solid thin aluminum high voltage wire to copper wire. [image]

Edit:

[Here](https://elektrotanya.com/panasonic_nn-mx25wf_mx25wm.rar/download.html) is where I got the Service Manual from.

[Here](https://servlib.com/faq.html#panasonic_zip_sgm) is the link to the program to view the SGM files.

The Service Manual specifies the diode with the cable as part ​F606V5G10XN, but can't find any info anywhere and no-one carries it or has any info on it.

I went to a local electronics shop and they sold me the same diode that goes to the chasis from the capacitor. Would it be ok to use that one?

Comment: for the part number, look for the panasonic microwave parts catalog on the web

Comment: That's the first thing I did... Problem is that most sites I've found don't have a picture for it.

Comment: do you mean that it is not in the service schematic?

Comment: capacitors only have 2 leads. all of them. are you talking about the big metal part? that's a transformer, and they come in myriad variations, many of which are not interchangeable.

Comment: Finally found the schematic. Says the part with the cable is F606V5G10XN. There is no information anywhere. Contacted Panasonic, Encompass and others just say that it's discontinued and no other info. A local electronics shop tried to sell me the same diode that connects to the chassis.

Comment: @dandavis I meant terminals in each connection. I see why that brought up the confusion. I updated it. Since the original capacitor had 3 terminals on one side of the capacitor and used them all up I ended up splicing one cable, since the new one has two terminals. That's what I was trying to say.